# How do you describe informal relationships between people in politics (including corrupt ones)?

Tags: word-request, word-meaning

Can I use the word 'close' to mean "having an informal relationship with", for example in politics? As in

> A businessman **close** to the president bought a state-owned steel mill at a fraction of its independently estimated value.

I thought I could, but then I looked it up in Lexico and now I'm not so sure.

Answer (score 1):

That is a correct use of the word "close".  It suggests that the businessman is a friend of the President.

Comment: "(of a person or relationship) on very affectionate or intimate terms" — do you think it accurately describes the intended meaning? Or is Lexico faulty in this case (it may definitely be)?

Comment: intimate, but not "sexually intimate".  Intimate can just mean "closely acquainted; familiar." It does describe the intended meaning.